# Why could it be that my function is not getting called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one file like this:

```
//function accessLinkClick(e) {
//    e.preventDefault();
//    $('#registerLink', '#loginLink')
//        .unbind('click', accessLinkClick);
//    dialog(this);
//}

function accessLinkClick(e) {
    alert("hi")
}
```

and another:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#loginLink','#registerLink')
.bind('click', accessLinkClick);
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a id="loginLink" class="button dialogLink" title="Login" data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Login" data-title="Admin" data-entity="n/a" data-dialog="UserAdmin" href="#">Login</a>
```

I changed the name of the function in the first file, ran my code and got an error saying the function did not exist. So this proved to me that the accessLinkClick function was known. I then changed the function name back to accessLinkClick.

I step through the code and I see it goes to the bind event so it looks like the function is being bound.

However when I run my code and click on loginLink then nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong here? Should I take away the parameter for the function for it to work?

Comment: is there a reason for including commented code?

Comment: @Tig: Probably to make the question complete with the actual code as well as the temporary test code. Seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: @graystateiscoming fair enough. I guess I just don't see it. Alert is as good as an example as any.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is your selector:

```
$('#loginLink','#registerLink')
```

You need one string instead of two:

```
$('#loginLink, #registerLink')
```

The reason for this is the [2nd argument to the jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is the *context*. It looks for an element matching the 1st argument `#loginLink` that is a descendant of the 2nd argument.